# Unable to connect to MySQL database but able to connect to database server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a dynamic website for connecting pages with database I used the code as follows. connection with server is Ok but unable to select database. data base name, user id, password, ip of host all gave but not working. please help....

```
define('DB_NAME', ''); 
define('DB_USER', '');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_HOST', '');

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    if (!$link) {
     die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
         }
else {
      echo 'connected to server..................';   }


$db_selected = mysql_select_db($DB_NAME, $link);

if ($db_selected) {

print "Database Found";

}
else {

print "Database NOT Found";

}
```

Comment: What error your are getting?

Comment: And please use either PDO or MySqli. Mysql is deprecated now.

Comment: Tripple check your database name for typos and case sensivity. Also make sure you do actually have permissions to select that specific database inside the RDBMS.

Answer (score 0):

Mysql has been deprecated and will eventually be removed.  Consider using PDO or MySqli.

Here is a link to the PHP documentation page for making connections to a database using MySqli.

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.connections.php

If you follow the instructions carefully you 'should' be able to connect.  If not, perhaps you can post the error message you receive.

Comment: the error massage is as followsvia "TCP/IP Failed to connect to MySQL: (2002) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."

Answer (score 0):

Try to give proper credential to connect to mysql server. `mysqli_connect("localhost","root","password","db_name");`